# invoke ios app in background and perform run some code when app closed or terminated

Tags: ios, swift, background

I am new to Swift. I have created an app that stores data locally in SQLite when there is no internet connection. Later, it needs to check for an internet connection every 30 minutes and upload the saved data to a server, even if the app is closed or terminated. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: That is not possible to invoke application automatically in iOS, but alternatively there is some way of background notifications, may be help with your logic or not, but you can check it here how can run app for 30 seconds in background by sending push notifications.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app#overview

Answer (score 1):

iOS terminates all the processes once application goes to background or terminated to optimise the performance. So by default it is not possible to do so. You can do this by using **Background Fetch**. For clear understanding you may refer to this [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started). One more [reference](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-is-terminated) for the same.